# tryin' to enumerate all available Wifi network with J2SE

Tags: java, windows, api, wifi

I'd like to find out a way to enumerate all available wifi networks using Java 6.0 and any third-party API.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find a solution to this problem, all I got is a library that I can't use because I don't have any example.

I'll be very pleased if someone could help me.

The target platform is Win XP/7.

Edit: the library I found is named jwlanscan

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that jwlanscan is intended as a library.  I downloaded it and it seems that it contains a gui application that scans for wireless networks and displays information about them.  There is also a utility class that scans for information and writes the information to the console.  I guess you could use that and parse the information, but I don't think there is a public API intended for the purpose you are looking for.

Comment: Ok. I'm quite surprised, because I knew that some librairies exist for android. I'm still looking forward :)

Comment: If you open up the jar file and decompile the class files you can see how they do it.  It is basically done using JNI.  There are two Native methods `getNetworkAdapterInfo` and `getWirelessApInfo`.  So you could just use the dll that is included and call the native methods.  Not sure of the licence implications though.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you very much, my goal isn't to set up a product that has to be selled, but is mainly self educative. So u help me in great way :)